# Dropdown chosen item doesn't display corrently in mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a drop down;

```
  <select name="pizzaSize" type="text" id="pizzaSize" >
    <option value="Small"<?php echo ($pizzaSize== 'Small') ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>Small</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="large">Large</option>
    <option value="XL">XLarge</option>
  </select>
```

When I submit the query, under the pizzaSize column, it just says pizzaSize. Any thoughts?
Note: I just focused on covering the small option, I suppose once I get that working it will be the same for other options

Comment: you can echo `$pizzaSize`, if it have no value, you can check your sql commend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When rendered, your HTML would look like:

```
<option value="Small" selected="selected"Small</option>
                                        ^-- '>' missing here
```

As it's evident from the syntax highlighting, you're missing an angled bracket before `Small`.

Change your code to include the angled bracket:

```
<option value="Small"<?php echo ($pizzaSize== 'Small') ? ' 
selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Small</option>
```

Although, `Small` size will be selected by default in all the cases. You need to define a default option for this to work properly:

```
<select name="pizzaSize" type="text" id="pizzaSize" >
    <option value="default">Select size</option>
    <option value="Small"<?php echo ($pizzaSize== 'Small') ? ' 
    selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Small</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="large">Large</option>
    <option value="XL">XLarge</option>
</select>
```

[**Demo.**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Rz60il)

Comment: Doesn't work, I'm still getting the same result, as it is the column name that is assigned as a variable. Is it supposed to contain any array?